# Is it possible to run Telegraf in Docker (and get accurate metrics)?

Tags: docker, influxdb, telegraf

I wish to run [telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf) - the influxdb metrics collector - via docker on my hosts in order to collect their host-level metrics. This is actually quite easy: an official docker image is available at [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/telegraf/).

In an ideal world, a dockerized telegraf would expose the exact same metrics as a non-dockerized version - but I'm guessing its not quite possible. So i'd like to know what are differences (for example, the number of file descriptors) and how to minimize them (for example, would running the docker container with --priviliged flag help?)

Comment: Have you seen this approach: https://www.jacobtomlinson.co.uk/monitoring/2016/06/23/running-telegraf-inside-a-container/? I'm not 100 percent sure, but if you mount host system directories and docker.sock as your telegraf container volumes you might actually achieve what you want (using telegraf's docker plugin).

Comment: @misko321 thanks for this link! I have seen it (and another one like it), but have yet to try this out. Was (and still) hoping to get an authoritative answer from someone with first hand experience.

Comment: fwiw, looks like running telegraf within docker returns the correct uptime. I suspect it would also return the correct load5, as to other things, I dont know.